# Find the ratio of Surface area$^3$ and volume$^2$ of an sphere

Tags: geometry

IF surface are and volume of a sphere are S and V respectively,then value of $$\dfrac {S^3}{V^2} $$

a) $32$ unit;
b) $9$ unit;
c)$18$ unit ;
d)$27$ unit;

I know the formula $S=4\pi r^2$ and $V=\dfrac43\cdot\pi r^3$.I tried to solve it and my answer is $36\pi$ which seems to nowhere of any option.

Comment: Something doesn't jibe here:  why are the choices given in "units"?  If the ratio is written as intended, the $36 \pi$ should have _no_ units.

Comment: I dont know it was asked question and I didn't get right answer thats why I am asking.okay no units find out only number

Comment: Your $36\pi$ is correct for the ratio in the body of the question.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that there is apparently something missing or written down incorrectly, because the _choices_ makes no sense...

Comment: why are you just behind the unit @RecklessReckoner please get the number.and I've double checked the question

Comment: Don’t forget, friends, questions on tests and homeworks are made up by humans, not by gods.

Comment: this question was asked in national level exam and their answer key shows answer is d.If there were any typo they mention it in answer key that's why I am so freaking out

Comment: And people wonder about the state of education and education evaluation today...  I'm afraid it is possible that, if you have omitted or mistyped nothing yourself, that this is a botched problem statement. (And, yes, this _does_ happen on national exams and standardized tests.)

Comment: I've checked so many times.I'll post scanned copy it so that all people satisfy that question is in its original state.

Answer (score 3):

$S=4\pi r^2$ and $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$

$$S^3/V^2=\frac{(4\pi r^2)^3}{(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3)^2}=\frac{64\pi^3r^6}{\frac{16\pi^2r^6}{9}}=36\pi$$

Comment: Squaring a pie gives a cubical pie!?

Comment: In denominator there is $4^2$ so it will $16$ not $64$ and same as for 3

Comment: So $3^2$ is 27?!

Comment: no there should be 9

Comment: So now that we are all in agreement... there is something suspect about the problem statement.

Comment: okay i will post scanned copy of question

Comment: edited now, thank all of you

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for the ratio is wrong, the ratio, $R$ is simply: $R=S/V=3/r$, which you cannot find without $r$. But if you want to find $S^3/V^2=36 \pi $, see the other answer. Like the comments said, there is something wrong in the options you were given as possible answers

Comment: It is not an equation.and r is canceled out in expression please check it

Comment: Thanks! I meant expression, and by mistake I named the ratio $r$, same way as the radius. Corrected.

Comment: what is wrong with my answer? why the negative vote? (the original question had the ratio, without exponents in the title)

Comment: downvoter please leave the comment